# PHP table sorting, filtering and pagination

Tags: php

I've been trying to find I good solution to using MySQL query data for Ajax tables with pagination, sorting and filtering.   I've tried DataTables and really don't like it.  I started trying FooTables but for some reason I'm having difficulty finding one good complete example of using FooTables with PHP and MySQL data.

What would you recommend for achieving Ajax driven Pagination, Sorting and Filtering with PHP right now that has a good piece of complete working example source code to learn from?

I'm using jQuery but not Bootstrap right now for my web pplications.

Thanks!

Comment: Write your own.

Comment: What's wrong with DataTables? You can customise the F*Rk out of out.

Comment: Or use MYSQL `LIMIT` clause

Comment: Check this [Footable add data](https://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/docs/examples/advanced/loading-rows.html), for filter data you can use the [events](https://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/docs/examples/advanced/loading-rows.html) about filtering to send the query to server...

Answer (score 1):

http://jtable.org/ might be a good candidate. I am using https://datatables.net/ now but I have used this in the past with good success. Jtable has good documentation and a pretty flexible plugin. The documentation also has sample code with mysql and php.